# using join if there is a record

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a query like this:

```
select tractions.id,tractions.expired,tractions.succ,tractions.cradit_end_date,
                      tractions.user_id,users.family,tractions.coupon_code,users.username,traction_details.title,
                traction_details_sub.title as sub_title,tractions.coupon_parent,tractions.coupon_id,tractions.coupon_property_id
                from tractions,traction_details,traction_details_sub,users
                  WHERE
                  tractions.app='mobile'
                  AND tractions.succ = 1
                  AND tractions.user_id=$user_id
                  AND tractions.id = traction_details.tr_id
                  AND tractions.id = traction_details_sub.tr_id
                  AND tractions.user_id = users.id
```

now,some records in `tractions` have not any `tr_id` in `traction_details_sub` table.

how to check if `traction_details_sub` table have `tr_id` then join these tables ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to ANSI joins (they have been nearly universally available for a long time) and use an outer join for tables that may not have records:

```
SELECT
    t.id
,   t.expired
,   t.succ
,   t.cradit_end_date
,   t.user_id
,   u.family
,   t.coupon_code
,   u.username
,   d.title
,   s.title as sub_title
,   t.coupon_parent
,   t.coupon_id
,   t.coupon_property_id
FROM tractions t
LEFT OUTER JOIN traction_details d ON t.id = d.tr_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN traction_details_sub s ON t.id = s.tr_id
JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE t.app='mobile' AND t.succ = 1 AND t.user_id=$user_id
```

Note how this syntax moves tables away from the `FROM` clause into separate joins, with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` designating tables with optional rows. Also note how the last three conditions of your `WHERE` clause became `ON` conditions of the corresponding joins. Finally, note the use of *table aliases* (i.e. `t` for `tractions`, `d` for `traction_details`, `s` for `traction_details_sub`, and `u` for `users`) to shorten the query.

Answer (score 0):

First select all tr_id from traction_details and after repeat you sql query add condition IN tractions.id (all id available)

Answer (score 0):

Use left join for `traction_details_sub` table. If there is no matching record, then you will get `tds.title` as `null`.

```
select t.id,t.expired,t.succ,t.cradit_end_date,
t.user_id,u.family,t.coupon_code,u.username,td.title,
tds.title as sub_title,t.coupon_parent,t.coupon_id,t.coupon_property_id
from 
tractions t 
    inner join 
traction_details td
    on t.id = td.tr_id

    left join 
traction_details_sub
    on t.id = tds.tr_id

    inner join 
users u 
    on t.user_id = u.id
WHERE
    t.app='mobile'
    AND t.succ = 1
    AND t.user_id=$user_id
```